# Nodejs ORM for MYSQL

Tags: database, mysql, node.js

The **purpose** to find recommendation for a node-js package to interact with mysql db which can achieve following objectives

1. It should be highly documented
2. Resolve maximum of MYSQL query handling in robust manageable manner
3. Can consume maximum features provided from MYSQL itself
4. Which can help in migration to other db system if needed such as migration from mysql to mongo, mysql to sql, mysql to oracle any
5. Which can easily be replaced in future with other package

Answer (score 1):

[Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/) is a promise-based Node.js ORM for Postgres, MySQL, MariaDB, SQLite and Microsoft SQL Server. It features solid transaction support, relations, eager and lazy loading, read replication and more.

Also take a look at https://knexjs.org